# Add JPanels dynamically to either a JTable or a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

Currently working on a project and I need to add a panel I've made to a scrollpane or a table dynamically. The scrollpane should start out empty and add the panels.

The `GuiConstructor` is where i make the window.

My problem is that if I don't comment out the `setSize` in the `GuiConstructor`, the window starts out very small.
Secondly, when i press the add button, it doesn't add the panels.

```
public GuiConstructor(){
    super(APPLICATION_NAME);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    LoopControlWindow loopwin = new LoopControlWindow(connect);
    add(loopwin , BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    //this.setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}


public class LoopControlWindow extends JPanel {

IConnector connect;

public LoopControlWindow(IConnector connect) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    this.connect = connect;
    initPane();
}

private void initPane() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    FolderSearchComp fsc = new FolderSearchComp(connect);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    JButton button = new JButton("Add");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.add(new FolderSearchComp(connect));
            scrollPane.getViewport().setView(panel);
        }
    });



    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));


    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical of this style of GUI app. You need to tell the layout manager how big to make the Window initialy without using `setSize()`. The way to do this is to override `getPreferredSize()` to return a default size. In your case:

```
public LoopControlWindow extends JPanel {
    private Dimension size;

    public LoopControlWindow() {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackge("your.java.package");
        size = new Dimension(prefs.getInt("width", 800), prefs.getInt("height", 600));
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

By doing it this way you can store the user preferences for the window dimensions but also provide sensible defaults to start.

You should also make sure that this JPanel is your main panel and is added to the JFrame at BorderLayout.CENTER to ensure that your window gets drawn properly. All other panels should be somewhere inside this one.

Once you have this set up calling `pack()` will work correctly.

Comment: plus one, but JFrame.pack() is designated for completing this ..., miss that in your answer

Comment: I dont get the usernodeforpacker method, what does this do?

Comment: @JonasOlesen You can have global data that will be accessible no matter what user is logged on. User node is for user specific data. Each user has its own set of values. You pass a class to your base package to keep your name unique.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, you need to specify a size for the initial JFrame().  One way is to call setSize as you are doing.  Another is to override getPreferredSize() to return the default size.  And one other option is to find the size of the user's monitor and set the JFrame to be a percentage of that size.  That way you can ensure your window always fits on your user's screen.

```
    int height = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().
            getBounds().height;
    height = (int) (height * .85);
    int width = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().
            getBounds().width;
    width = (int) (width * .85);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
```

Second, you need to call revalidate() and repaint() anytime you add or remove from a layout in order to see the changes.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel.add(new FolderSearchComp(connect));
        scrollPane.getViewport().setView(panel);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
});
```

One note on border layout.  The components in it will not resize with your JFrame.  Whatever component that is placed in BorderLayout.CENTER will, however.  That component will grow to fill all extra space as the JFrame grows.  It will also be the component that shrinks when the JFrame windows gets smaller.